# Where is the "Print Preview" option for Safari on Windows?

Tags: windows, safari, preview, printing

I am unable to find a way to generate a print preview using Safari 5.0.7533.16 on Windows XP Pro SP3.

Google searches indicate that either a) there is a way to generate a print preview that I cannot find, or b) this functionality used to exist but has been removed, at least for some Windows platforms.

I know that Chrome (which also uses the WebKit engine) does not yet have a Print Preview option (according to Google, this is planned for version 6) - perhaps the possible absence of the option in Safari 5.0 is related to a hurdle in the latest WebKit involving print previews.

If anyone could shed some light on how to generate print previews in Safari on Windows, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl+P or Ctrl+Shift+P?

Comment: Thanks, but neither of those worked. Ctrl+P is the same as selecting "Print..." from the Safari menu, while Ctrl+Shift+P brings up the "Page Setup" window but does not offer a preview.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hit Alt+F to bring up the file menu, and you should then see Print Preview as your 12th option. (I do). It's a bit unfortunate that they don't make it easier to find!

Answer (score 0):

Double-click the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and it should open a menu on top. Then from the "Document" dropdown menu you should see "print preview".